# Optimize Server for Traffic Spikes (Drupal)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, amazon-ec2

We have a fairly intensive Drupal installation running on a large EC2 server instance. The system takes registrations for campaigns that we host, and when we send out an invitation email the numbers of responses spike to around 1,000 per minute for the first ten or twenty minutes.

The system is running on a fairly standard LAMP installation, using the latest version of Drupal 7. I guess I have three questions:

1.) Should this amount of load be maxing out this size server? The install has the Organic Groups, Tokens, and Webforms modules running.
2.) Are there Mysql/Apache server tweaks that will minimize the amount of load per connection—shortening 'keep alive' time, etc.?
3.) Are there Drupal tweaks that we should implement to do something similar—maybe consolidating SQL calls?

I know this is a lot. Any ideas, suggestions, or critisisms will help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an opcode cache like APC installed?  Also, you should definitely shorten your KeepAliveTimeout.  The default 15 seconds (if I remember correctly) is horribly too long.  Also, it might help to know exactly how large of instance.  15 requests per second isn't insanely heavy, but a normal server running Apache with heavy PHP request (Drupal), it is definitely going to hurt.

Comment: Corbin, Thanks for the info! We'll shorten the KeepAliveTimeout right away, and check the opcode cache—I think we have APC installed.

Comment: If you do any of your own database operations, cache them in memcache - it's a really easy win that can add a good bit of performance.

Comment: also try boost . Its a drupal module which should improve performance.

Comment: Its really kind of hard to tell because we don't have any information on whats actually happening in your application. I would say most likely its not an issue with apache configuration. The servers I run can push 30,000 - 40,000 xml api requests / min on the c1.medium machines and it could probably be modified to handle more if it was setup by someone who understands apache more than myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high server load with Drupal, combination of **NGINX+PHP-FPM+APC+MySQL+VARNISH** will be the best option.
If you are using multiple system behind ELB, you can use MEMCACHE instead of APC. You should use MySQL Replication in your architecture along with load balancer. 
You can tune the server configuration of NGINX and PHP-FPM separately. If any process of PHP-FPM is taking time you can terminate that particular request  (request_terminate_timeout, request_slowlog_timeout ). You can check all the configuration related info here [PHP-FPM configuration](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File)

Also if you are using AWS, you should try to utilize their other services too in your architecture like S3 as CDN, ElastiCache, Cloudfront etc.

You can also use Google Page Speed service